# hbbtv app test/debug on a real TV

Tags: javascript, hbbtv

Is there a way to manually test/debug hbbtv app on a real TV.

I already tried plugins for opera/ff plugins and successfully run through static validators like http://hbbtv-live.irt.de/validator/.

Comment: You can setup a local name server and capture one of the official AIT URLs and direct them to your own web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using the following approach:

Take a Modulator like the Dektec DTU 315 (http://www.dektec.com/products/USB/DTU-315/) and the Brahms Software of the IRT (https://www.irt.de/en/products/media-services-and-applications/brahms/)

then you can also create you "own TV Station"

With the Brahms Software you can simply create your signal, take any video and add you hbbTV content to the signal.

Then the only thing you need to do is to find the TV station on your TV and start using the hbbTV application there

Comment: I'm also interested in developing and testing on real devices but haven't found a simple online guide to getting set up.  

Can the open source OpenCaster software generate the required TS files to launch an app?  Would I require any additional software?

As a cheap alternative to the DTU-315, does this modulator look like it meets the specs? http://www.hides.com.tw/product_opencaster_eng.html#310685  

If not, what specs do I need to look for to develop for HbbTV 1.5 and 2.0? 

Lastly, where can I find the hbbtv API docs?

http://www.hides.com.tw/product_opencaster_eng.html#310685

Answer (score 0):

Kai comment is right. I will just add some other ways for HbbTV testing on real devices, which I tried.

1. [Suitest](https://suite.st/pricing.html), complete solution, which is great for debugging and automated testing
2. [Mautilus HbbTV Playout kit](https://www.mautilus.com/products/hbbtv-playout-kit/) for quick testing on many devices - it's a small box broadcasting a local DVB-T multiplex.